# CSS Styling from External URL

Tags: css, shopify

Im not sure this is possible but Shopify allows a collection of items to be displayed on an external site and generates the code for you, effectively a type of iframe, i can obviously edit the styles of it using the inspector but when refreshing the page changes will be lost, is there a way to style and keep changes when using iframes or other similar embeds?

Comment: If it's not on your domain or owned by you, no.

Comment: Try googling Shopify themes: https://docs.shopify.com/manual/using-themes.